# Track traffic usage for StrongSwan connection using telegraf

Tags: iptables, strongswan

I'm looking to track total traffic usage by a StrongSwan IPSec connection. The initiators and responder are behind NAT so my plan was to have an updown script which adds the necessary firewall rule, with the necessary comment for telegraf.

What is the best way to do this? My thoughts were to put the following in the raw prerouting table:

```
-t raw PREROUTING -s [VIRTUAL_IP] -m comment --comment "host00_up1" -j ACCEPT
-t raw PREROUTING -s [REMOTE_IP] -m comment --comment "host001_down" -j ACCEPT
```

However, from testing (when running `iptables -t raw -nvL`), it doesn't seem to be counting all the traffic? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you look into [RADIUS accounting](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EapRadius#Accounting)?

Comment: The config at the moment is multiple site to site connections with a PSK. However I will look into the viability of RADIUS account. Thanks